# Sorting based on Date in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here is my API Service , i need to get a list of calculation using an api but sort it based on descending order of Date, with the current implementation Its ascending

```
    /*
     * Get  Risk Evaluation based on id
     */
    public List<RiskEvaluation> getByTest(String test) {
        return riskEvaluationRepository.findByTest(test);
    }
```

The controller is

```
@GetMapping("/{test}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "gets", notes = "Get all the Risk Assessments based on TEST.", response = RiskEvaluation.class, tags = {"GetsAllRisksforaTEST",})
    public List<RiskEvaluation> getByTest(@PathVariable("test") String test) {
        return scoringService.getByTest(test);
    }
```

the current output is getting with this API is

```
{
        "accountID": null,
        "bap_id": "cccccccccc",
        "release_version": "1.9",
        "risk_level": "Medium",
        "risk_score": 2,
        "createdOn": 1533584332466,
        "updatedOn": 1533584332466,
        "id": "8340f05c-06c4-430a-bbbd-a53d0ce60dea"
    },
    {
        "accountID": null,
        "bap_id": "cccccccccc",
        "release_version": "1.9",
        "risk_level": "Medium",
        "risk_score": 2,
        "createdOn": 1533584551115,
        "updatedOn": 1533584551115,
        "id": "ae175b92-805d-46b5-8f67-95795e232057"
    },
    {
        "accountID": null,
        "bap_id": "cccccccccc",
        "release_version": "2.0",
        "risk_level": "Medium",
        "risk_score": 2,
        "createdOn": 1533584718584,
        "updatedOn": 1533584718584,
        "id": "d19177ef-b8c4-4951-bbdb-4e4d7274be81"
}
```

How can I sort it based on the value `createdOn`

Comment: If data is currently ascending, does that mean you're already specifying an order somewhere? If so, how about you show *that* part? Anyway, if it is already sorted ascending, and you want descending, just [reverse the list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JpaRepository, you can pass a org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable object with the page, size and the sort order you want.

For example:

```
int page = 0, size = 10;

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, new Sort("createdOn", Sort.Direction.DESC));
```

...

Hope it works!

Comment: Remember: the page and size will give you an amount of object depending on what you select.

Answer (score 0):

Into you scoringService, do you have a method that's calling a RiskEvaluation repository, right? Probably to do it, its being used a JpaRepository or CrudRepository, in anyone if it has a findAll, you can use:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM RiskEvaluation r ORDER BY createdOn ASC")
List<RiskEvaluation> findAll();
```

Or

```
List<RiskEvaluation> findAllOrderByCreatedOnAsc();
```

You can see the examples in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details.

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);

  // Enables the distinct flag for the query
  List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);
  List<Person> findPeopleDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling ignoring case for an individual property
  List<Person> findByLastnameIgnoreCase(String lastname);
  // Enabling ignoring case for all suitable properties
  List<Person> findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling static ORDER BY for a query
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameDesc(String lastname);
}
```

Comment: If your are using other repository/DAO implementation, please, paste your code here in the post and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdOn"));
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)